# Getting id and then placing in values

Tags: angularjs, node.js, strongloop

For the AddVisitController, I created a visit model that takes in the properties like title, start date, end date and description. it will then redirect me to a page where I can click on a button to add in trips. All the properties are stored into one model. To add trips into the visit model, I want to take the id of visit before I can upsert the trips values. How do i get the visit id?

```
  .controller('AddVisitController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Visit', function ($scope, $state, Visit) {
        $scope.visits = [];

        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            Visit
              .upsert({
                  vTitle: $scope.visit.vTitle,
                  startDate: $scope.visit.startDate,
                  endDate: $scope.visit.endDate,
                  dDescription: $scope.visit.vDescription
              })
              .$promise
              .then(function () {
                  $state.go('create-trip');
              });
        };
    }])
```

Add trips controller

```
    .controller('AddTripController', ['$scope', '$q', 'Visit', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope, $q, Visit, $stateParams, $state) {  
    $scope.visits = [];

      $q
        .all([
          Visit.find().$promise,
          Visit.findById({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise
        ])
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        Visit
          .upsert({
              day: $scope.visit.day,
              date: $scope.visit.date,
              tTitle: $scope.visit.tTitle,
              startTime: $scope.visit.startTime,
              endTime: $scope.visit.endTime,
              tDescription: $scope.visit.tDescription
          })
          .$save()
          .then(function (visit) {
              $state.go('main-feed');
          });
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Visit module to return the response data, and include the Visit id in the response.

```
.then(function (visit) {
    $state.go('create-trip', {visit: visit._id});
});
```

Make sure you define the params in your state definitions.

```
$stateProvider.state('create-trip', {
  params: [
     'visit'
  ],
  templateUrl: 'templates/create-trip.html',
  controller: 'addTripController'
});
```

Take a look at: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls